# PHP PDO foreach issue

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, pdo

So I have a php function that updates 2 columns in a database. It looks like this:

```
$fields = array("firstname" => "Joe", "lastname" = "Dunno");

$stmt = $connection->prepare("UPDATE users SET firstname = :firstname, lastname = :lastname WHERE user_id = :user_id");

foreach ($fields as $key => $value)
{
    $stmt->bindParam(":" . $key, $value);
} 

$stmt->bindParam(":user_id", $user_id);
```

However when i execute the statement for some reason it likes to update firstname and lastname both to Dunno instead of Joe and Dunno.

I tried echo'ing the `$key` and `$value` and it prints out correctly.

For some weird reason if i use this for loop it works correctly.

```
for ($fieldsKeys = array_keys($fields), $x = 0; $x < count($fields); $x++)
{
    $stmt->bindParam(":" . $fieldsKeys[$x], $fields[$fieldsKeys[$x]]);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`bindParam`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) binds to a variable, that's why both fields are set to the same value (the last value of `$value`). You should use [`bindValue`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) instead:

```
$stmt->bindValue(":" . $key, $value);
```

In your code, PDO remembers that it needs to use `$value` variable for `:firstname` and `:lastname`. At statement execution time the `$value` is `Dunno`, so both fields get this value. If you use `bindValue`, PDO does not remember the variable that was used, but its value, and this is what you need.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll accept your answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: In the event that somebody will find it and will actually need to `bindParam` (for example if the values in the array can change before the statement execution) you can do `$stmp->bindParam(':'.$key, $fields[$key]);`